# Duplicate Element Elimination in C

Tags: arrays, c, duplicates

I am given to solve this question in C (it is **not** graded, just a LAB exercise.):

> Use a single-subscripted (one-dimensional) array to solve the following
> problem. Read in 10 numbers, each of which is between 10 and 100, inclusive. As each number is
> read, print it only if it’s not a duplicate of a number already read. Provide for the “worst case” in
> which all 10 numbers are different. Use the smallest possible array to solve this problem.

I want to and tried to solve this problem by using pointers and writing a removeElement function but it partially works and as I enter more than one duplicate and/or do it consequently, the output becomes more wrong. I wrote my code in separate files, so I'll add them in order. Also I want to clarify that I tried realloc function too but it didn't work either. My core algorithm is: as the duplicates come, decrease the newSize and allocate the memory to this new array that has the new size, then transfer the non-duplicated elements from the old array. I've provided a test case, too.

```c
/* main.c */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "header.h"
int main(){
   int* initialArray = NULL; /* array that takes all inputs and have duplicates */
   int* newArray = NULL; /* array that should have the non-duplicated elements only */

   int SIZE = 10;
   int newSize = SIZE;
   int input = 0;
   int locCtr = 0;

   initialArray = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * SIZE);
   newArray = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int) * newSize);

   printf("Welcome! Please enter your 10 numbers, between 10 and 100, inclusive! \n");
   while(locCtr < 10){
       scanf("%d", &input);
       if (input >= 10 && input <= 100) { //input istenen sınırlar içerisindeyse
           if(locCtr == 0){
               printf("Value: %d \n", input);
               initialArray[locCtr] = input;
               newArray[locCtr] = input;
               locCtr++;
           }
           else{
                if (isDuplicate(initialArray, SIZE, input) == 0){ //duplicate yoksa
                    printf("Value: %d \n", input);
                    initialArray[locCtr] = input;
                    locCtr++;
                }
                else if(isDuplicate(initialArray, SIZE, input) == 1){ //duplicate varsa
                    initialArray[locCtr] = input; //inputumuzu görebilmek için kaydediyoruz
                    newSize--;
                    newArray = removeElement(initialArray, newSize, input);
                    locCtr++;
                }
            }
        }
        else { //input sınırlar içerisinde değilse
            printf("Invalid input! Please enter your numbers in the interval of [10,100]! \n");
        }
    }
    
    printf("Your initial array is: ");
    printArray(initialArray, SIZE);

    printf("Your final array is: ");
    printArray(newArray, newSize);

    printf("Bye bye! \n");

    free(initialArray);
    free(newArray);

    return 0;
}
```

```c
/* header.h */
int* removeElement(int* oldArray, int newSize, int input);
int isDuplicate(int* array, int SIZE, int input);
void printArray(int* finalArray, int SIZE);
```

```
/* functions.c */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "header.h"

int* removeElement(int* oldArray, int newSize, int input){
    int* newArray = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * newSize);
    int j = 0; //newArray indeksi
    for(int i = 0; i < newSize; i++){
        if(oldArray[i] != 0){ //0 değilse al duplicate ise 0 yapıyor
          newArray[j] = oldArray[i];
          j++;
        }
    }
    return newArray;
}

int isDuplicate(int* array, int SIZE, int input){
    for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){
        if(array[i] == input){
            printf("Duplicate found! \n");
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

void printArray(int* finalArray, int SIZE){
    printf("[%d ", finalArray[0]);
    for(int i = 1; i < SIZE - 1; i++){
        printf("%d ", finalArray[i]);
    }
    printf("%d] \n", finalArray[SIZE - 1]);
}
```

*A test case:*

```
Welcome! Please enter your 10 numbers, between 10 and 100, inclusive!
10
Value: 10
20
Value: 20
30
Value: 30
40
Value: 40
40
Duplicate found!
Duplicate found!
50
Value: 50
50
Duplicate found!
Duplicate found!
60
Value: 60
75
Value: 75
80
Value: 80
Your initial array is: [10 20 30 40 40 50 50 60 75 80]
Your final array is: [10 20 30 40 40 50 50 1128087892]
Bye bye!
```

Thanks for your help in advance and I am sorry if there are any mistake(s) in my question format (I couldn't find any solutions that use pointers on Stack Overflow.).

Comment: You can probably use a simple array of 10 ints, all initialized to zero, and simply put each new, unique input value into the first available 0-valued slot. Also, wonder why it says "in which all *20 numbers* are different".

Comment: Actually I modified the question to have 10 inputs but forgot to change that part. It takes long to enter 20 inputs, sorry.

Comment: @cafce25 Hi, actually I thought I clarified my thoughts, I wrote the question, and I've explained the algorithm that I've tried to implement, also I've asked how can I achieve my goal with pointers. Sorry for the confusion. How can I be more specific?

Comment: @cafce25 please try to be more kind. I specified that I am trying to solve this with pointers, not with the arrays itself, I know what an array is and how to declare an array.

Comment: By "use the smallest possible array", does it mean use the smallest possible array that would be required to handle the worst case (i.e. 10 inputs), or the smallest possible array that is required to store the unique inputs?

Comment: @jarmod Thank you for your suggestion but I am trying to solve this problem by using pointers. Do you have any advice on how to do so?

Comment: _"Use the smallest possible array"_ - It would have 9 elements as I see it but for practical reasons, I'd make it 10, [like this](https://godbolt.org/z/YescKre1G)

Comment: Unclear why you need a removeElement function. When would you need to remove an element? Isn't it simply a case of *not* adding a previously-seen value to the array?

Comment: @jarmod it works this way: when a duplicate occurs, that function is called and non duplicated elements are added into the new array but the name is confusing, sorry.

Comment: The basic algorithm can be: "Check if the new input is already in the array. If so, report it as a duplicate. If not, report it as a new number and add it to the array." There is no need to remove anything from the array.

Comment: @IanAbbott that is the tricky part, when I asked this to my instructor they just said start with size 20, then 19, then continue trying. this is one of the states that confused me. sorry for my late response.

Comment: Just before the tenth number is read, the number of possible states is 877,564,803,947 (1 to 9 unique numbers have been seen, and this number is the sum of 91!/82!/9! ways to choose 9 numbers out of 91 plus 91!/83!/8! ways to choose 8, and so on). That is between 2^39 and 2^40, so the “smallest possible array” is one with 40 bits.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I am new to C, so, I'm trying to understand pointers and thought this question was an opportunity to do it.

Comment: @EricPostpischil thank you for your detailed comment. so I am not to use pointers for this question I guess.

Comment: guys, I explained this confusion above, it takes long to enter 20 inputs but 10 is ok for me, so I modified the question but forgot that part, sorry for the confision again:)

Comment: Also, by "smallest possible array", do they mean number of elements or the size in bytes? The size in bytes can be reduced by a factor of `sizeof(int)` easily enough because the allowed values can all be represented by `char`.

Comment: thanks for all of your help everyone, I solved my problem by not using pointers

Comment: @IanAbbott i don't know really. as I wrote above they only said try 20 then try 19 then continue trying which is not clear at all...

Comment: One reasonably simple way to save bytes is to mark off the seen numbers in an array of `unsigned char`. There are only 91 allowed numbers from 10 to 100 inclusive (100-10+1 numbers), and 91 single-bit flags can be stored in an array of `unsigned char` of length `(91+CHAR_BIT-1)/CHAR_BIT` (or `(100-10+CHAR_BIT)/CHAR_BIT` or `(100-10)/CHAR_BIT+1`). If `CHAR_BIT` is 8, that is 12 bytes. (I suspect this is what @TedLyngmo had in mind for their "naive algorithm".)

Comment: @IanAbbott I don't think they meant something complex.

Comment: I believe the point of "use the smallest possible array" is that you avoid using an array of flags with 99 elements. Instead you should use an array with 10 elements containing the values.

Comment: @Barmar: To make the array as small as possible (given that you are recording prior elements), it should have nine, elements, not ten. There is no reason to record the tenth since there is nothing coming after it. It only needs to be tested against the prior nine.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Good point, although I hate writing special cases for `if (i != ARRAY_SIZE - 1)` to treat the last element specially.

Comment: @PhoebusApollon I chose to put my naive algorithm up as an alternative. It's the only answer that is not useful according to popular vote. I think it's helpful so I'll leave it up.

Comment: thank you so much, everyone! sorry for my late answer though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For such a limited number of numbers, I would suggest a simpler approach.

- Make an array of 10 numbers where you store the already seen numbers.
- If a number not previously seen is read, keep it in the array, otherwise, don't.

A base implementation:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SIZE (10)

int main(void) {
    int seen[SIZE]; // storage for all the unique numbers
    int idx = 0;    // index of current candidate for being stored

    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i) {
        // Read a number and check that it's valid. Terminate otherwise:
        if (scanf("%d", &seen[idx]) != 1 || seen[idx] < 10 || seen[idx] > 100)
            exit(1);

        // Check if the currently entered number has been entered before:
        bool found = false;
        for (int j = 0; j < idx; ++j) {
            if (seen[j] == seen[idx]) { // seen it before, break out
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!found) { // not seen before, print it and increase idx to store it
            printf("%d\n", seen[idx++]);
        }
    }
}
```

This uses as many array elements as there are possible unique values. Even with this naive algorithm we could make the array `SIZE - 1` since we don't need to actually store the last number to check if it's already entered. Implementation simplicity wins over the requirement to make it as small as possible when the cost is this low.

Comment: thank you so much for all of your help, ted.

Comment: @PhoebusApollon You are wecome! I'm glad it helped!

Answer (score 0):

As you cant change the size of the arrays to use minimum allocation you need to use dynamic allocation (it creates the array with exact number of distinct elements). It is a very simple, not optimized but easy to understand :

```
int inArray(const int *array, const size_t size, const int val)
{
    int result = 0;
    if(array && size)
    {
        for(size_t index = 0; index < size; index++)
        {
            if(array[index] == val)
            {
                result = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}

int *distinct(const int *arr, const size_t sourceSize, size_t *destArraySize)
{
    int *distinctE = NULL;
    *destArraySize = 0;
    
    if(arr)
        for(size_t index = 0; index < sourceSize; index++)
        {
            if(!inArray(distinctE, *destArraySize, arr[index]))
            {
                int *tmp = realloc(distinctE, (*destArraySize + 1) * sizeof(*distinctE));
                if(tmp) 
                {
                    distinctE = tmp;
                    distinctE[*destArraySize] = arr[index];
                    (*destArraySize)++;
                }
                else
                {
                    free(distinctE);
                    distinctE = NULL;
                    *destArraySize = 0;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    return distinctE;
}

int main(void)
{
    size_t size;
    int arr[] = {10, 20, 30, 40, 40, 50, 50, 60, 75, 80};
    int *destArr = distinct(arr, sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]), &size);

    if(destArr)
    {
        printf("Result size: %zu\n", size);
        for(size_t index = 0; index < size; index++)
            printf("%d ", destArr[index]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    free(destArr);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/593EM8bsb

Comment: thank you for your answer. i'll study it in detail.

Answer (score 0):

You would be well-advised to separate out the logic for managing a dynamically allocated array. *The below does not error-check `malloc` or `realloc`.*

```
typedef struct vec {
    size_t sz;
    size_t cap;
    int *arr;
} vec;

vec *init_vec(size_t init_cap) {
    vec *v = malloc(sizeof(vec));
    v->sz = 0;
    v->cap = init_cap;
    v->arr = malloc(sizeof(int) * init_cap);

    return v;
};

int vec_full(vec *v) {
    return v->sz == v->cap;
}

vec *min_grow_vec(vec *v) {
    if (!vec_full(v)) return v;

    v->cap++;
    v->arr = realloc(v->arr, sizeof(int) * v->cap);

    return v;
}

vec *push_vec(vec *v, int val) {
    min_grow_vec(v);
    v->arr[v->sz++] = val;

    return v;
};

void free_vec(vec *v) {
    free(v->arr);
    free(v);
}
```

You can now use your O(n^2) algorithm to scan for repeated elements.

```c
int mem_vec(vec *v, int val) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < v->sz; i++) {
        if (v->arr[i] == val)
            return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And this makes `main` trivial to write.

```
int main(void) {
    vec *v = init_vec(1);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        int x;
        scanf("%d", &x);
        if (mem_vec(v, x)) {
            printf("Duplicate found.\n");
        }
        else {
            printf("Value: %d\n", x);
            push_vec(v, x);
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, you should get into the habit of validating your input with `scanf`, and your algorithm is )(n^2) which is fine for the data sample size you're working with but will not scale well at all.

If the range of data remains small (10-100) then you could keep a lookup table and flip bits to determine if a number has already been input. This would allow for O(n) time complexity, which is very good.

However, if the range of acceptable input increases tremendously, this ceases to scale well in terms of memory usage and you'd likely want to use something like a binary search tree which would allow for O(n * log n) time complexity, which is less good than O(n) but clearly much better than O(n^2).

Comment: thank you for your answer. i'll study it in detail.